# How to copy csv file from google storage to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, google-cloud-storage, azure-data-lake

i'm trying to upload files to Azure Data Lake from Google Storage using Python.
Following this url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-python#create-filesystem-client
but the issue is that the files are in Google Storage and not local , so i try to use instead of the local file path the public URL for the file in GCS that looks like "https://storage.googleapis.com//<****filename******>.csv" , But i get the error that it couldn't open the file!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhZs0.png)

Anyone did this before , is this the right way to do this or is there other way

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the API you are using requires the `lpath` to refer to a local path and not another cloud path. So I see two options:

1. Download the file from Google storage to your local location and then upload it from there using the ADLS API.
2. Alternatively, use something like Azure Data Factory to orchestrate the data movement without having to do a local copy.

Comment: Hi Michael , indeed i use lpath ,the first option may not work  for me because i need to write the app (Flask) and deploy it to Google App Engine and schedule it in CRON , i don't think download to local path will work!! maybe i'm wrong i havn't tried it , the second option sound good but it doesn't have a connector to Google Storage so it has to be a custom activity and i have no idea how to implement this

Comment: I would suggest to add the Azure Data Factory tag to see if they can help with the data movement.